# Python 3.x Collecting Mouse Events

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouselistener

I'm just trying to learn the "Listener" function. But I couldn't manage to break any loop with mouse clicking. Here is an example:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import time

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    counter = 0
    while True:
        print(counter)
        counter += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if pressed:
            break

with Listener(on_click = on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

When I'm running this code, my PC is getting very slow. I'm a beginner. I need to use listener with normal codes.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `on_click` function is called twice. Once when you press the mouse button down, and again when the button is released. Since the function will be called twice, we cannot break the loop that the first function call creates by calling it again with a different value for the state of the mouse button.

I am assuming your intention was to print counter every second the mouse button is held down. I have a snippet below for you that uses threading to accomplish this, and each call to the `on_click` function can read the state of the mouse as well as the state of the thread used for printing.

While using `time.sleep()` within a function it causes the thread it was called in to sleep. When you only have one thread running it causes the entire program to sleep every second. I believe that your computer was not lagging, however the mouse would appear to lag because your input is being interrupted by the call to sleep every second.

```
from pynput import mouse
import time
from threading import Thread

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    thread = Thread(target = threaded_function)
    if pressed and thread.is_alive() == False: 
        thread.start()
    if not pressed:
        if thread.is_alive():
            thread.join()
        return False

def threaded_function():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count+=1
        print(count)
        time.sleep(1)

with mouse.Listener(on_click = on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```